# ng-init does not initialize my selected model

Tags: angularjs

I have a select option where I get a list of titles i.e. Mr, Mrs, Dr etc. from an API, the code looks like this in the front end:

```
<select class="form-control" name="titleSelect" id="titleSelect" ng-options="option.value for option in titleData.availableOptions track by option.key" ng-model="adult[$index].selectedTitle" ng-init="adult[$index].selectedTitle = titleData.availableOptions[0]"></select>
```

And this in the controller:

```
var getPassengerTitle = PassengerDetailsAndCardDetailsService.getPassengerTitle();
```

PassengerDetailsAndCardDetailsService is service, where I get the API data i.e. the title data. Furthermore this service returns a promise.

This is where I set the title Data:

```
    getPassengerTitle.then(function(result){                
        $scope.availableTitles = angular.fromJson(result.titleList);
        $scope.tempListOfTitles = [];

        for(var key in $scope.availableTitles){             
            $scope.tempListOfTitles.push({key : key, value : $scope.availableTitles[key]});
        };      

        $scope.titleData = {
                availableOptions: $scope.tempListOfTitles,
        };

    });
```

When I try to ng-init to the first option (that is Mr.) it does not work as in a blank option is shown. However when I tried statically defining the titleData in an object it works, could you please help me?

UPDATE:

I failed to mention that the title data is inside an ng-repeat to support input for multiple people/passengers in this case. Therefore I'm using adult[$index] where it creates an ng-model for each person/passenger.

Comment: you define incorrct ng-model.

Comment: @SSH please check my update

Comment: can you create pulkner. why use $index in ng-model?

Comment: do you want selected defualt value?

Comment: yes exactly. I use $index because it's inside an ng-repeat and I dynamically create adult objects to hold a single passengers details. I cannot create a plunker to retrieve the data from the API data as it secure. I have tried doing something like this `ng-init="adult[$index].selectedTitle = {'key':'0','value':'Mr'}"` which works.. but it is statically defined.

Comment: Your use of `ng-init` to create an array is misuse of `ng-init`. You shouldn't use ng-init to add a lot of unnecessary logic. You should use a $scope variable from controller instead. Please refer this for appropriate usage of `ng-init`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @AdityaSingh I understand, do you think it is alright to call a function in the controller side instead? like `ng-init="initializeTitleData()"`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the required behavior you want, but if you want to initialise the title on selecting an option you can either use the value from `ng-model` or use the event handler `ng-change`. Here is an example [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jurapu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) which handles the change and assigns the new value to ng-model. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
myapp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
 var vm = this;
  vm.adult = {
              'selectedTitle':'1'
            };
   vm.titleData = [
                   {'key':'0','value':'Mr'},
                   {'key':'1','value':'Ms'},
                   {'key':'2','value':'Dr'}
                  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller="Main as ctrl">
<div class="select-style">
  <select  ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in ctrl.titleData" ng-model="ctrl.adult.selectedTitle"></select>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```